# Disable View after onClick in Compose

Tags: android, onclick, android-jetpack-compose

I want to disable the arrow Image after it's clicked, and have the option to enable it again after another event.

```
Image(
                painterResource(R.drawable.arrow_back_btn),
                contentDescription = "back",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
                    .clickable(onClick = onArrowClick)
                    .layoutId(R.id.arrowBackBtn),
                onArrowClick = {enabled = false}

            )
```

the last line I just improvised - the onArrowClick is recognized but 'enabled' is not

Answer (score 15):

Use an internal state to define if the composable is clickable. When `enabled` is `true` the image is clickable, when `false` the image is not clickable.

Something like:

```
var enabled  by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }

Image(
    painterResource(R.drawable.ic_add_24px),
    contentDescription = "back",
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        .clickable(
            enabled = enabled,
            onClick = { enabled = false } 
        )
        .layoutId("arrow")
)
```

To enable again just set `enabled = true`. For example:

```
Button(onClick = {enabled = true}){
    Text("Enable again")
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand 1. where my onClick method onArrowClick goes then since you  replaced it with enabled = false. 2. don't understand the button code. It's not a button it's a clickable image. And where would that go? In the fragment code?

Comment: @galaxigirl It is just an example. The important part is the use of a state to enable/disable the Image:`modifier.clickable(enabled = enabled)`. You can set the value as you prefer.

Comment: {enabled = false} ... enabled shows an error 'An argument is already passed for this parameter'