# clickable set to null still sets the clickable with ripple effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Image which needs a clickable based on a condition. I tried to set it to null, but still the image is clickable there is ripple effect

I want to disable clickable for the image

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ohme_logo_white),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(0.7F)
        .clickable { 
            if(state.clickable) {
                onPressed()
            } else {
                null
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320024/disable-view-after-onclick-in-compose

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting clickable (or it's `onClick` argument to be precise) to null like this. You used the trailing lambda syntax, which is equal to this:

```
.clickable(
    onClick = {
        // your if - else block
    }
)
```

Which means that if `state.clickable` is false, your onClick is a function that returns `null`.

In fact, `onClick` is not nullable in `.clickable` modifier, so you can either make use of the `enabled` argument, which makes the most sense in your case:

```
.clickable(enabled = state.clickable) { onPressed() }
```

Another option would be to conditionally apply `.clickable`:

```
Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth(0.7F)
    .then(
        if (state.clickable) {
            Modifier.clickable { onPressed() }
        } else Modifier
    )
```